# Fail to load data to Hortonworks Sandbox in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hortonworks-data-platform

Hi I am very neophyte to hadoop and when I first run this command 
`LOAD 'Pig/iris.csv' using PigStorage (',')` the error popped out:

```
LOAD 'Pig/iris.csv' using PigStorage (',');
2014-09-05 06:04:04,853 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.12.1.2.1.1.0-385 (rexported) compiled Apr 16 2014, 15:59:00
2014-09-05 06:04:04,885 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: /dev/null
2014-09-05 06:04:07,077 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.impl.util.Utils - Default bootup file /usr/lib/hue/.pigbootup not found
2014-09-05 06:04:14,699 [main] INFO org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
2014-09-05 06:04:14,699 [main] INFO org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2014-09-05 06:04:14,699 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to hadoop file system at: hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020

2014-09-05 06:05:11,826 [main] INFO org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
grunt> LOAD 'Pig/iris.csv' using PigStorage (',');
2014-09-05 06:05:13,203 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Encountered " <IDENTIFIER> "LOAD "" at line 1, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
<EOF>
"cat" ...
"clear" ...
"fs" ...
"sh" ...
"cd" ...
"cp" ...
"copyFromLocal" ...
"copyToLocal" ...
"dump" ...
"\\d" ...
"describe" ...
"\\de" ...
"aliases" ...
"explain" ...
"\\e" ...
"help" ...
"history" ...
"kill" ...
"ls" ...
"mv" ...
"mkdir" ...
"pwd" ...
"quit" ...
"\\q" ...
"register" ...
"rm" ...
"rmf" ...
"set" ...
"illustrate" ...
"\\i" ...
"run" ...
"exec" ...
"scriptDone" ...
"" ...
"" ...
<EOL> ...
";" ...

Details at logfile: /dev/null
```

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LOAD` creates a relation. You need to assign that to a variable so that you can do something with it later:

```
L = LOAD 'Pig/iris.csv' using PigStorage (',');

DUMP L;
```

Comment: Thanks it works!! One thing that I am curious about Pig is can I run one line of command by highlighting it as in R or the whole script has to be run at one time?